# Looking for a simple Batch script that modifies file name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a list of files in a folder that end with `.swf`.

I want to change all those files from `X.swf` to `X<some number>.swf`.

How can I do that?

Comment: do you want to count that number up with every file or is it alway the same number?

Answer (score 3):

This little script will change all `*.swf` files into the equivalent `*_42.swf` files.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.swf') do (
    set fspec=%%a
    set newfspec=!fspec:~0,-4!_42.swf
    echo ren !fspec! !newfspec!
)
endlocal
```

Actually, as it stands now, it will just echo the commands that it wants to execute. Once you're happy they're correct, you can just remove the `echo` from that renaming line above.

It works by using `for /f` to get a list of all SWF files and then using string manipulation to:

- remove the last four characters (the`.swf` extension); then
- add a new `_42.swf` extension onto the end.

And, please, make sure you back them up first :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following one-liner directly from the command prompt:

```
FOR %F IN (*.swf) DO RENAME "%F" "%~nF123.*"
```

where *`123`* stands for your number of choice.

Alternatively you could create a batch file and take advantage of its ability to accept parameters. Use the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "suffix=%~1"
FOR %%F IN (*.swf) DO RENAME "%%F" "%%~nF%suffix%.*"
```

Now if the batch's name is `renamer.bat`, you can invoke it like this:

```
renamer.bat 2011
```

and it will add `2011` to the name of every `.swf` file in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `<X>` in your description is supposed to be constant and you don't explicitly require a batch script to solve your problem, you can use Windows Explorer as mentioned in an article by Microsoft titled "[Rename a file](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Rename-a-file)".

Here's a an extract from said article:

"You can also rename several files at one time, which is useful for grouping related items. To do this, select the files [then press F2]. Type one name, and then each of the files will be saved with the new name and a different sequential number at the end (for example, Renamed File (2), Renamed File (3), and so on)."